# return { value1, value2 }; in a function call not working in C++20

Tags: c++, c++17, c++20

I am trying to compile codes written in c++17 with c++20. But the following function getTest() doesn't work anymore:

```
struct Test
{
    Test() noexcept = default;
    Test (const Test&) noexcept = default;
    ~Test() noexcept = default;
    int a, b;
};

Test getTest()
{
    return { 1, 2 };
}
```

In c++17 getTest compiles, but with 20 the compiler complains that "No matching constructor..."

Is it correct to fall back to return Test(1, 2), given that I make a custom constructor with `Test (int first, int second)`

Comment: You need to work though [Aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) - it keeps changing.

Comment: Get rid of your constructors and destructors, it should work.